# playing a video with subtitles (no audio) using gstreamer pipeline is giving me errors

Tags: gstreamer

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=subtitleseng.srt ! subparse ! overlay. filesrc location=video.mp4 ! qtdemux ! queue ! theoradec ! ffmpegcolorspace ! subtitleoverlay name=overlay ! xvimagesink

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstSubtitleOverlay:overlay: Internal GStreamer error: negotiation problem.  Please file a bug at http://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=GStreamer.
Additional debug info:
gstsubtitleoverlay.c(799): _pad_blocked_cb (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstSubtitleOverlay:overlay:
Subtitle sink is blocked but we have no subtitle caps
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQTDemux:qtdemux0: GStreamer encountered a general stream error.
Additional debug info:
qtdemux.c(3891): gst_qtdemux_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQTDemux:qtdemux0:
streaming stopped, reason not-linked
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

I even tried

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/subtitleseng.srt ! subparse ! input-selector ! sub. filesrc location=video.mp4 ! decodebin ! input-selector ! streamsynchronizer name=sub ! subtitleoverlay name=sub ! xvimagesink

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause.
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFileSrc:filesrc1: Resource not found.
Additional debug info:
gstfilesrc.c(508): gst_file_src_start (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFileSrc:filesrc1:
No such file "home/usr/Downloads/video.mp4"
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Giving this error even if the file is present.

please help me solve this or directions that would help me do the same

Comment: Please tidy up your question - you post multiple very similar gst-launch pipes (I mean one with escaped '!'  and one without it) - also they use different paths to the files - its very confusing. Post one gst-launch - one debug output and describe whats wrong.. the file is not there - you are missing / before home ;) also I think you cannot type the gst-launch twice in same command - this is not how it works (if I understand the 0.10). Another thing is - switch to 1.x, 0.10 is unsupported for long time.

Comment: I regret for the mistakes i made in posting the question
$ gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=subtitleseng.srt ! subparse ! input-selector ! sub. filesrc location=videocartoon.mp4 ! decodebin ! input-selector ! streamsynchronizer name=sub ! queue !  subtitleoverlay ! xvimagesink

Comment: as I am not able to add the error in the same comment due to constrained length.the error of the above is
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFileSrc:filesrc0: Internal data flow error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(2865): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFileSrc:filesrc0:
streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated (-4)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...

Comment: 2nd pipe is obvious - incorrect path.. you can either use relative path like `~/something/subs.srt` or you can do `subs.srt` if its in current dir where you are playing, or you can use abs path like `/home/something/subs.srt` .. so knowing this please remove the second pipeline from question because its misleading. Just use proper location and concentrate on the not linked error..

Comment: Now to the real error in first pipeline - why do you use input selector? it chooses either subtitles or audio.. so I guess its not what you want. Do it like this - decode the mp4, decode the subtitles and overlay it on raw frames with subtitle overlay and then just display on autovideosink or whatever you use

Comment: Is this what you mean ? 
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=subtitleseng.srt ! subparse ! sub. filesrc location=videocartoon.mp4 ! decodebin ! streamsynchronizer name=sub ! queue ! subtitleoverlay ! autovideosink

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
libva info: VA-API version 0.36.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_36
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
Redistribute latency...
Its getting struck at this

Answer (score 1):

Its working for me like this - and I indeed see the subtitles:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=cartoon.mp4 ! decodebin ! video/x-raw ! videoconvert ! subtitleoverlay name=over ! autovideosink  filesrc location=subs.srt ! subparse ! over.
```

The trick was in videoconvert before subtitleoverlay.. 
HTH